# Do you recommend using the same like box in different websites?

Tags: web, facebook-likebox

I have a main website about tourism of a city, in that site i have the like box plug.

Now i'm building two new websites about restaurant and hotels of the same city.

Do you recommend using the same like box in different websites?

Similar contents about the same city, the idea is to get more likes faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using different websites, then I would recommend using different like boxes. I'm sure no one would appreciate clicking like on something only to have it not be what they actually were trying to like.

Comment: so it does not cause any technical conflict???
I understand what you are saying and i will follow your advise, yet i would like to know. Thanks!

Comment: I personally don't have any experience doing so and wouldn't know how to go about implementing it.